# oidc - virtual application

Tags: openid-connect, azure-appservice

I have an application (ASP.NET MVC) that uses OIDC for SSO.
This needs to run as a virtual application within an Azure App Service.

When run as a stand alone app locally, it works fine.
I have deployed the app by itself to an App Service and it works as well.

When run as a virtual application, the controller for the redirectUri is reached but the middleware doesn't seem to hit the SecurityTokenValidated method.
The user is not authenticated even though inspection (chrome dev tools) of the POST from the IDP to the redirectUri DOES contain a token. I have verified contents of the token via https://jwt.io/

I can reproduce the issue locally (by running via Visual Studio) and setting the 'Project Url' property to contain a folder path to simulate where it will live as a virtual application when deployed. (http://localhost:44339/admin - rather than simply http://localhost:44339 for example)

However, I am not sure WHY it is failing to hit the SecurityTokenValidated method in this scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual application", exactly? Are you referring to IIS _Application Scopes_?

Comment: _"but the middleware doesn't seem to hit the SecurityTokenValidated method"_ - Have you set a breakpoint in the middleware to find out what's going on?

Comment: A ‘virtual directory’  that contains a completely different set of files for another application it has its own web.config, bin folder etc. When browsing the root application it is simply represented as a folder path (/admintool for example)

Comment: I have set a breakpoint in the overridden delegate method containing my custom logic, but it doesn’t get hit in the virtual directory scenario. The innards of the library must be skipping it for some reason. This is OWIN OIDC for older .NET(4.8)

Comment: You do know that in IIS, an _Application Scope_ is not the same thing as a _Virtual Directory_, right? Your post (and your reply) does not confirm that you specifically configured it as an Application Scope.

Comment: I'm not (can't) configuring IIS directly. This is an 'Azure App Service'. The configuration blade has a 'virtual applications and directories' section. It is indeed configured as 'application'. It will not run if configured as a 'directory'.

Comment: Thinking on your comment, my reproduction may be imperfect locally. I am using IIS Express (via Visual Studio) and each app runs on a different port. I'm not sure I am correctly setting up one to be a virtual on the other. I guess I can set up IIS itself to be more like the deployed environment (though it will still be different due to their natures). Any suggestions on proper local config?

Comment: Compare their `applicationHost.config` files.